# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in / failed to open stream:

Tags: php, http-headers, warnings

Error:

> PHP Warning: 
>   file_get_contents(https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=Star-Wars:-Episode-VII---The-Force-Awakens&page=7&per_page=5&access_token=XXX):
>   failed to open    stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal
>   Server Error in search.php on line 3 PHP Notice:  Trying to get
>   property of non-object in search.php on line 6

### Code :

```
<?php
/* https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos */
$vdata = file_get_contents('https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query='.$search.'&page='.$p.'&per_page=5&access_token='.$vimeo_token.'');
$vresponse = json_decode($vdata);
if ($vresponse->data==NULL){
echo '';    
}else{
foreach ($vresponse->data as $vresult)
{ 
//...
```

Comment: You should check if the file_get_contents was successful and the json_decode, maybe with `if ($vresponse) {`, before you try to access properties from it. Also `file_get_contents` isn't the best way to scrape, you should check out cURL or a library like Guzzle HTTP.

Comment: Json_decode chooses to convert as associative array. you can convert it to an object. @Barmar is correct. thank you for correction!

Comment: Actually, it should be `if ($vdata)` before trying to call `json_decode`

Comment: @risyasin It defaults to objects, you have to use the second argument to make it an array.

Comment: The resource is unavailable with those parameters.

Comment: you sure $vimeo_token is correct?..